# How to check if webrtc peers communicated in p2p mode or relay mode

Tags: webrtc

Say:

1. A and B in the same Lan,
2. A and B in different Lan.

but connect by webrtc logic, how can I check if it's really communicated by p2p or by relay server (turn server)? I can see multiple icecandidate exchanged each other but not sure which one is used actually!

For case 1) I think A and B should use local Lan connection to talk to each other but How can I confirm it's!

For case 2) it maybe use p2p connection or use relay server for media relay, how can I know what's the actual connection being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call the peerconnection.getStats() API once the ICE connection is up (i.e. on iceconnectionstatechange to connected or completed).
Then iterate the statistics to find the currently active connection, find the pointers to the local and remote candidate and look at their candidateType field.

The sample at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/ shows most of this but doesn't show the candidateType, only the ip and port.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below method is not good answer but it should work:

1. If A and B in the same lan, after connection finished, disconnect internet connection but keep Lan with A and B, if A and B can communicate successfully, then it must be communicated by Lan since internet disconnected already.
2. If A and B in different lan, just remove the turn server to connect A and B, if A and B can be connected and communicated successfully, then A and B should be not use relay server p2p communicate. otherwise if using turn server can communicate and without turn server can not, then it must be using turn server in relay mode. (i think it's a fake p2p since a relay server is in the middle of communication).