# how to know RTCDatachannel's current connection type: host/srflx/prflx/relay?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

when local RTCDatachannel connected to remote RTCDatachannel, I wanna to konw the connection type: host/srflx/prflx/relay..

I try to parse the following string, but it's not the current one which is connected

```
RTCPeerConnection.localDescription.sdp
RTCPeerConnection.remoteDescription.sdp
RTCPeerConnection.currentLocalDescription.sdp
RTCPeerConnection.currentRemoteDescription.sdp
```

I can use chrome://webrtc-internals/ to see the connected candidate type

Answer (score 1):

The getStats() API provides that information. In essence, you search for the `transport` stats, traverse to its selected candidate pair using `selectedCandidatePairId` and then can access the local and remote candidates and their respective types.

In practice it is a bit more complicated, in particular if you want to support Firefox as well. The code around
https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/js/main.js#L229
provides a full sample.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53133745/how-to-check-if-webrtc-peers-communicated-in-p2p-mode-or-relay-mode?

only one "transport", yes? then use selectedCandidatePairId to find the pair, so i will get pair.localCandidateId and pair.remoteCandidateId, finally local-candidate and remote-candidate, they contain candidateType fields... yes?

Comment: Yes. There can be more than one transport but only in cases where you actively do something (and typically not for datachannel-only connections).